# React RadioGroup into Table Cell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a page of component that having many radio button componsed with table. Like this:

[image]

I made this with Material UI's `RadioButton` and its `Table` component. It's now working  well, but the problem is it's blinking. Perhaps every time when I hit button, it calculate previous state and latest one, finally re-render whole of page.

In typical HTML, I remember if I set `name` of element to same, I don't need any option, But In React, especially [this example](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selection-controls/#radio-buttons) used `this.setState(...)` and each radio to `checked={this.state.selectedValue === 'value'}`,

It seems to me very complicated, and the most sad point this is slow! How can I avoid whole re-rendering page? or Is there any suggestion to newbie?

My code snippets looks like below...

```
<TableBody>
    {SIM_INSTRUCTOR_ITEMS.map((el) => {
        return (
            el.list.map((item, index) => {
                itemRows++
                return (
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>{item.content}</TableCell>
                        {item.possible.map(rating => {
                            let rowCount = itemRows-1;
                            return (
                                <TableCell key={uuidv1()}
                                           className={[classes.cell, classes.cell_center]}>
                                    <Radio
                                        checked={this.state.item_ratings[itemRows-1].ratingPoint == rating}
                                        onChange={ (e) => this.handleRadioChange(e, rowCount)}
                                        key={ 'radio-'+uuidv1() }
                                        value={ rating }
                                        name="radio-button"
                                        aria-label={ rating }
                                    />
                                </TableCell>
                            )
                        })}
                    </TableRow>
                )
            })
        )
    })}
</TableBody>
```

and I handle Radio Change and state like this.

```
handleRadioChange = (event, itemRows) => {
    const items = this.state.item_ratings;
    items[itemRows].ratingPoint = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ items })
};
```

How can I prevent re-render whole page when I hit radio button?

+) I heard `setState` make re-render page. Then how about using redux? If I use redux, can I prevent re-rendering?

Answer (score 1):

I removed `uuid()` to each table row, and each iterated element to create unique key.

and I change to updating not whole array but element of array using `immutable helper` in react.

Now it works better.